# Help with Direct comparison Test: $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

The Direct Comparison test states that if we have two series $a_n$ and $b_n$ with $b_n ≥ 0$ and $a_n ≤ b_n$ for all n. If b converges so does a. If a diverges so does b.

I was given the series $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^n}$ and I attempted to use the direct comparison test on this, but was unable to come up with a series that I could compare this to.

However this looks geometric series with |R|< 1 when N ≥ 2 so it should converge I think but it could also be a p series with P > 1 at N ≥ 2. When I asked my professor what methodology he would employ to find another series to compare this to he told me to compare it to either a p series or geometric series and "reason it out". How do I "reason this out"? What is the first step in the Direct Comparison Test and is there a sequence of steps that I can follow to arrive at a the right series or is it just trial and error and knowledge of different series formats?

Comment: Use either $n^n\ge 2^n$ or $n^n\ge n^2$, as your prof told you.

Comment: $\frac{1}{n^2}$ should converge but am I just allowed to just change the value of the power to a constant? I thought this was not allowed.

Comment: Every inequality which holds is "allowed". And these two possible comparisions are those hinted by your prof.

Answer (score 3):

When $n\geq 2$, $n^n\geq n^2$, so $\dfrac{1}{n^n}\leq \dfrac{1}{n^2}$ and, as $\displaystyle\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{n^2}$ converges being $2>1$, we deduce $\displaystyle\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{n^n}$ does too.

Comment: But how did you come up with this sequence of steps is there a methodology you follow or have you just done this question before?

Comment: $n^n\geq n^2$ is an obvious inequality, and the family of p-series is one the most used for direct comparison tests.

Comment: But what if the bounds were from 1 to $\infty$, then the inequality would not hold true. Also how do I find these inequalities? Is there a formula I don't know or do you just have to reason it out?

Comment: $\frac1{1^1}=\frac1{1^2}$, and anyway, the convergence or divergence of a series is independent of its first term (hence of its $r$ first terms, for any fixed $r$).

Comment: It doesn't matter, as long as it holds for $n$ bigger than some $n_0$ the test works. There is no formula, one has to practice and eventually some patterns are easy to recognize. Other times creativity is needed.

Comment: Wait never mind forget my earlier question I see how this holds true.